# UIHostingController not working with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**EDIT**

I am trying to place a UIHostingController within a UIScrollView but when I try to present the SumViewController the view has no height like in the picture.

If I set the height in the SwiftUI view then it works but I do not want to set the height of the view.

```
class SummaryViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var id: String = ""
    var sport: String = ""

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scrollView
    }()
    
    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = UIStackView.Distribution.equalSpacing
        stackView.spacing = 30
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return stackView
    }()
    lazy var contentView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: SummaryView(id: id, sport: sport))
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(hosting.view)
        scrollView.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        hosting.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height).isActive = true
    }

}
```

[image: ui]

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: you are not properly added scroll view in view

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691134/swiftui-view-and-uihostingcontroller-in-uiscrollview-breaks-scrolling) is already asked

Comment: I have made edits